# How to remove css files?

Tags: css, refresh

I am developing an enterprise application using Spring, Java, JSPs, Tiles, and JQuery.  I have several tabs that need a particular css file.  Each Tab corresponds to a JSP.  The JSP that needs the css file has the css include in it.  The problem I have is that once I load a css file needed in tab/jsp Foo, that css file is still active when I click on tab/JSP bar.  How do I make sure that when a user clicks on the jQuery tab, that all the css files from the previous tab/jsp are removed?  When I hit refresh, the problem disappears, is there a way to refresh automatically?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply adjust your CSS targets to be tab specific:

```
.tab-about h2 {
    /** ... **/
}

.tab-about p {
    /** ... **/
}

.tab-home h2 {
    /** ... **/
}

.tab-home p {
    /** ... **/
}
```

Comment: i was able to solve the problem by using JQuery:    $('#id_for_css').remove();  but it seems to me your answer would be a more fundamentally sound design approach; my resolution a band-aid.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

On clicking tab you are just changing the tab. On tab click if you redirect to the current url
e.g.

```
window.location = window.location; //Or put URL like window.location = 'some url here';
```

and put some logic (may b write a cookie) to select the tab that was clicked.

Comment: but I would recommend the answer from Mike G as well. Its the better idea.